# Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem

Tags: msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a scenario where i need to Zip two different  folders in different paths to a single Zip file using `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip`. Is that possible, if so how i can achieve it.

Ex: `C:\Folder 2  and D:\Folder 1 , to a single zip file Folder1.Zip`.